# Why Does the DataMemberAttribute Require Special Handling for Boolean Properties

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I've noticed that if a Boolean property in a data contract does not emit a default property, e.g.

```
    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
```

then setting the property to false results in a serialization error. This seems counter-intuitive, because the property has been set, it's just that it's been set to false. The solution is to always configure Boolean properties to emit a default value, then true will come across the wire as true, and false as false.

Just curious: is this a bug in System.Runtime.Serialization or the inevitable result of Boolean type semantics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think the behavior you seem to be sqying you're seeing is not a bug, or anything to do with the booleans.

The operation contract is marked with `IsRequired` set to true.  By default, `EmitDefaultValue` is set to true, but in the posted code it's been set to false.

The `EmitDefaultValue` attribute indicates whether or not to serialize the value if it is the default value (in other words, if the property was set to `false`, it would not serialize that property per your current definition).

Since the property is marked as required, if you set the value to `false` the serialization will fail (if `EmitDefaultValue` is false) because you're giving contradictory directions - you're saying this property is required for serialization, but don't serialize it if it's the default (false).

In a way I guess you could say it's because of the nature of boolean (it's either true or false, and false is the deafult), but in reality it's because of the way `IsRequired` and `EmitDefaultValue` interact.

Take a look at [Data Member DefaultValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx), specifically the "Interaction with IsRequired" section.

Comment: I see what you're saying. EmitDefaultValue doesn't care whether the value has been explicitly assigned or not, just whether the value of the property is equal to the default value for the type. So integers would work the same: all integers with value 0 will be dropped from the serialization unless EmitDefaultValue is true.

Comment: Correct.  Remember that in .NET variables do have a default value when they're declared - a value (like 0 for int) for value types and null for reference types.  When using automatic properties, the compiler will create the backing field(s) for you, so if you don't set a property explicitly, it will have the corresponding default value out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the conflict, you could use nullable bool (bool?) so if the value is explicitly set to false, it will be serialize as expected. Of course, make sure nullable bool data type is something your system can handle.

```
    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool? IsSet { get; set; }
```